# processing float in java

Tags: java, floating-point

in java, i have an array of floats, some of them are negative numbers, like :

```
3.04, 9.02, -4.2, -3.21, 0.02, -0.34
```

I only want to get the float numbers higher than 2, so I used :

```
if(number > 2.0 ) print.. etc
```

but what i get is not only the numbers >2, also the negative numbers :

```
3.04, 9.02, -4.2, -3.21
```

what could be the problem ?

Comment: Could you post a more complete code snippet to show exactly what you are doing?

Comment: How do you populate 'number'?

Comment: `what could be the problem ?` Looks to me like you took the absolute value of the numbers before the test.

Comment: the code is too large, actually i get the numbers from a file, each float number is written on a separate line, i read the line, and convert from string to float. and then apply the 'if' condition, could the problem be related to signed and unsigned numbers ?

Comment: Converting `String` to `float`... are you remembering to take the sign in as you parse the string?  You should _show_ us the code that assigns `number` and the part that prints it.

Comment: Java does not have unsigned numbers... however, you may have problems with your file reader/parser.

Comment: Try placing parentheses in the "if(number > 2.0 ) print.. etc" to this -> "if(number > 2.0) {print ..}", Maybe you're just printing all the numbers of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments and question, assuming we have a file named `numbers.txt` with content:

```
3.04 
9.02 
-4.2 
-3.21 
0.02 
-0.34
```

this code should do the trick (I ommited exception handling for readibility):

```
float[] floats = new float[100];  // adjust as needed

String fileName = "numbers.txt";
File f = new File(fileName);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

String line = "";

int i = 0;

while( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    if(line == null || line.isEmpty()) continue;  // just in case there are empty lines in file
    floats[i] = Float.parseFloat(line);
    i++;
}

br.close();

for (float number : floats) {
    if (number > 2.0) {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3.04
9.02
```

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell what the problem is without seeing code. Writing the *obvious* code from your description, it works fine:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float[] floats = { 3.04f, 9.02f, -4.2f, -3.21f, 0.02f, -0.34f };

        for (float number : floats) {
            if (number > 2.0) {
                System.out.println(number);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compare your code with mine - if you still can't get yours to work, please edit your question with your code.

Answer (score -1):

This is too long for a comment but it should be pointed out that if you write:

```
if (number > 2.0)
```

then you probably shouldn't be working with floating-point numbers because you don't understand yet how they work.

There's a good Wikipedia page on floating point numbers:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Then I suggest reading the 80 pages long *"What every computer scientist should know about floating-point numbers"*.

Basically: due to the limited precision of floating point numbers, comparison should typically always be done using an epsilon.

Things like: *if (number > 2.0)* are a big no-no.

Comment: I don't fully agree. *Equality tests* are indeed a no-no for floating point values, but `<` and `>` is usually not so critical (this of course depends on the domain, the range of values etc.). And overall, this is definitely not an answer to the original question - it would have been better to squeeze it into a comment.

Comment: @Péter Török: which is why I started with *"This is too long for a comment"*.   Equality are a no-no that is a given.  And > and < test have to be done using an epsilon and this is critical (or you get "Bad Things" [TM] like space shuttle blowing in the sky ; )   Btw I could give trivial examples where a < or > test without an epsilon will fail but this can be as trivially Googl'ed :)

Comment: would be quite interested to know which space shuttle blew up due to a floating point comparison without epsilon ;-) I understand how such tests can fail - my point was that < and > comparisons are rarely so critical in real life. (And if they are, one should use a `BigDecimal` anyway.)